# File IO in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, io

I am very new to eclipse, i have following line in my code:

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dvdinfo.txt"));
```

when implemented through a simple text editor and windows console it works fine but when run through eclipse it shows `FileNotFoundException`.

Yes, i do always keep the txt file in the same folder as the `.java` file that contains this code. Also in eclipse i have selected to have both my source code and my class file in the same folder.

Is there any different way to specify the name of a file in the same folder in eclipse.

Note: i am using windows 7 and eclipse 3.7

Comment: the problem has been solved, thanx everyone for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, i do always keep the txt file in the same folder as the .java file that contains this code.

That doesn't mean it's in the same directory when you're *running* the code.

> Is there any different way to specify the name of a file in the same folder in eclipse.

Same folder as what? If you want the file to be packaged up with the *output* of the build, you can specify it as a resource in Eclipse, but then you should be reading it using `Class.getResourceAsStream()` or `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`.

If you really want it to be a file, you may want to *either* specify an absolute filename *or* change the working directory in the Run configuration in Eclipse.

Comment: also i keep both my source code and my class file in the same folder so essentially it is in the same directory when i m running the code. It works fine when i run the code through console so how is it different in eclipse?

Comment: @SurenderThakran: Do you mean you've configured Eclipse to build into your source directory? Ick. But basically you should check your working directory when running in Eclipse.

Comment: Jon's correct, when you run in eclipse your default working directory is the project root.  Use the `Run>Run Configurations` menu to change your working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Unexpected FNFEs (especially with unqualified file names) tend to be because you are not looking in the directory that you think you are. Is the qualified file name included in the stack trace?

Try this;

```
File file = new File("dvdinfo.txt");
try {
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  ......
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
  //Note that writing to syserr is only for debugging - don't do this in prod
  System.err.println("Can't find " + file.getCanonicalPath());
  fnfe.printStackTrace();
}
```